# REACTJS insert variable into interpolated string

Tags: reactjs, interpolation

I'm trying to create a link in ReactJS, passing a search string.  What I want to create is

```
<td><Link to={{pathname: '/select_item', search: '?item_id=83'}}>Select</Link></td>
```

where the item id (in this example, 83) is replaced with the variable "itemId", which varies in a loop. If I hard code the itemId, as in the example above, then the link works.

I tried

```
<td><Link to={{pathname: '/select_item'0, search: '?item_id=`${itemId}`'}}>Select</Link></td>
```

but that doesn't work - the itemId isn't replaced, so the link text is

```
/select_item?item_id=${itemId}
```

I then tried

```
var path = "pathname: '/approve_item1', search: '?walk_id=" + item.id + "'";
<td><Link to={{path}}>Select</Link></td>
```

but that doesn't work either.

Can anyone let me into the secret as to how to insert a variable into an interpolation string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be wrapping the entire string in backticks.

```
<td><Link to={{pathname: '/select_item', search: `?item_id=${itemId}`}}>Select</Link></td>
```

More info on template strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

I think You could do that using **String Interpolation** like this:

```
<td><Link to=`/select_item?item_id=${itemID}`>Select</Link></td>
```

Check this for more explanation **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation**